# What is the max length of a "survey column" on Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

What is the max length of a survey question(column) on Sharepoint 2010? And can we think it is like a custom list's column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The survey column is ultimately a text filed so the rules apply to normal text filed also applies to this column too.

It has limit of 255 characters